# How to add leading zeros and specify decimal figures at the same time with printf

Tags: java, php, c, perl, printf

I know how to do X amount of leading zeros, and I know how to do X amount of decimal points. But how do I do them both?

I am looking to have 4 leading zeros with a decimal precision of 2: `0000.00`.
Therefore `43.4` would be `0043.40`

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Try this `printf` ([C](http://linux.die.net/man/3/printf), [Perl](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sprintf.html), [PHP](http://php.net/sprintf)) format string:

```
"%07.2f"
```

Comment: java has a printf too... (System.out.printf() )

Comment: @st0le: So does Python (via the `%` operator) but I didn't contribute the list of languages. Feel free to further edit the answer.

Comment: It would be worthy to mention that first number (7) means total length that includes integer part, fractional part and the FP dot itself (and optional "minus" sign as well).

Answer (score 9):

Here is the code you need:

```
float myNumber = 43.4;
DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("0000.00"); //use # for optional digits instead of 0
System.out.println(formatter.format(myNumber));
```

Answer (score 0):

Java: use the [Formatter](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html) class. Examples of expected usage:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
// Send all output to the Appendable object sb
Formatter formatter = new Formatter(sb, Locale.US);

// Explicit argument indices may be used to re-order output.
formatter.format("%4$2s %3$2s %2$2s %1$2s", "a", "b", "c", "d")
// -> " d  c  b  a"

// Optional locale as the first argument can be used to get
// locale-specific formatting of numbers.  The precision and width can be
// given to round and align the value.
formatter.format(Locale.FRANCE, "e = %+10.4f", Math.E);
// -> "e =    +2,7183"

// The '(' numeric flag may be used to format negative numbers with
// parentheses rather than a minus sign.  Group separators are
// automatically inserted.
formatter.format("Amount gained or lost since last statement: $ %(,.2f",
                balanceDelta);
// -> "Amount gained or lost since last statement: $ (6,217.58)"
```